# Integral of the function that is 1 a.e.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I have the following:
$\int_0^1\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\chi_{[0,1]}(x-t-k)dt$.
I know that sum is 1 for almost every $x-t\in \mathbb{R}$. Can I use that that is 1 everywhere since the integral wont change if the function is not 1 only on the set of measure 0? Also just to check,I am allowed to switch order of sum and integration?

Comment: Yes, almost everywhere is good enough. And you can switch the integral and  the sum because of non-negativity.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy